# Change truncation settings in Gradle

Tags: gradle, spock

When running Spock tests in Gradle (5.6.3) I see that the output can look something like this:

```
> :functionalTest > Executing test com.examp...baar.baaaaz.MyCustomGradleTasksP
```

In reality it should be like this if it showed the full path to the test running:

```
> :functionalTest > Executing test com.example.fooo.baar.baaaaz.MyCustomGradleTasksPluginFunctionalTest
```

Maybe it would also tell me which of the actual functional tests from that class it is running?

Is there a way to tell Gradle **not** to do this truncation so I can see **all** information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an internal implementation detail of Gradle itself:

```
private String createProgressLoggerDescription(TestDescriptorInternal testDescriptor) {
        DecoratingTestDescriptor decoratingTestDescriptor = (DecoratingTestDescriptor)testDescriptor;
        DefaultTestClassDescriptor defaultTestClassDescriptor = (DefaultTestClassDescriptor)decoratingTestDescriptor.getDescriptor();
        return "Executing test " + JavaClassNameFormatter.abbreviateJavaPackage(defaultTestClassDescriptor.getClassName(), MAX_TEST_NAME_LENGTH);
    }
```

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/testing-base/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/logging/TestWorkerProgressListener.java#L103

It may be possible to override this by implementing your own logger for Gradle as described here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:changing_what_gradle_logs

Comment: I believe you have found the right place with the first link and that being able to set MAX_TEST_NAME_LENGTH to something higher than 60 would take care of my problem. Thanks for digging this up!